# Cloudflare kills dashboard + Relationship tab error. Any ideas?

Tags: upgrade, relationships

Drupal 6.36;  CiviCRM 4.5.8

I am experiencing two problems after making changes to my site. Not sure if the problems are related. I will start troubleshooting but any guidance would be very helpful.

**1. Civi dashboard** loading icon spins and dashlets don't load. This may be related to us installing Cloudflare (http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,27176.msg142612.html#msg142612).

**2. Relationships tab** generates error on click. Screen loads but the relationships list doesn't open. The following two popups appear:

> DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1
>
> DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_1 - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Clicking the Add relationship button opens the dialogue and allows it to be completed, but on saving the above errors appear again.

**Background:**

- Moved the site to a faster server with no apparent problems
- 6 hrs later...
- Upgraded Drupal 6.36 security release. All seems fine.
- Tried to install Civi4.6.4 but it errored out so I reverted to the
  4.5.8 backup. It was late and I didn't copy the error :-(
- Implemented Cloudflare. Civi is appreciably faster. Cloudflare needs www. domains so I set up a redirect in htaccess and updated the Civi paths and resource URLs. Also cleared all caches

Thanks
Davy

Answer (score 3):

Disabling Cloudflare or switching off popups as suggested didn't help. Neither did setting up a Cloudflare PageRule to bypass all Civi pages

But this worked:

I followed the instructions here  (http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Ensuring+Schema+Integrity+on+Upgrades) to clean up my database schema, and then the upgrade to 4.6.4 worked - and fixed the problems.

Answer (score 0):

First (and easiest to do) disable Cloudflare and see if the site operates correctly.  Disabling Cloudflare is super easy to do.

This may be related to the pop-up forms in recent versions of CiviCRM.  You can go to civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display and unselect "Enable Popup Forms" and see if that corrects the problem as well.